# How does a canvas library fit in the Flux Pattern and React?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs, flux

I like how Flux focuses on a separation of concerns and a unidirectional data flow, but this also makes me wonder how i should incorporate a canvas library like [fabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/).

FabricJS creates a object model on a native canvas element to extend and simplify functionality. My question is whether to initialize a FabricJS canvas element in the View (React component) and handle all actions on the canvas directly in the View and only store and update the canvas state **or** set the canvas element in the View and then register all canvas actions with a Store and use the View to dispatch Actions?

Answer (score 1):

Just send actions to store and listen for changes with canvas if there are updates - update canvas. Everything goes to action, action calls store it saves data and emits changes. Component listens for changes and updates it's state and view.